# JFrog Artifactory OSS - Missing Pre-defined Repositories

Tags: artifactory

It's my first attempt to use JFrog Artifactory OSS
I've used this helm chart - [artifactory-oss](https://github.com/jfrog/charts/tree/master/stable/artifactory-oss) to deploy it

And while doing some configurations I notice that there is a list of pre-defined repositories that are missing in JFrog Artifactory OSS. Is this as expected, are they available only in the paid version?

I get the list from documentation:

```
libs-release-local - Your code releases
libs-snapshot-local - Your code snapshots
ext-release-local - Manually deployed 3rd party libs (releases)
ext-snapshot-local - Manually deployed 3rd party libs (shapshots)
plugins-release-local - Your and 3rd party plugins (releases)
plugins-snapshot-local - Your and 3rd party plugins (snapshots)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When first deploying an [Artifactory OSS](https://jfrog.com/community/open-source/) server, there is only one generic repository created with the name *example-repo-local*.

In order to create the repositories you mentioned, you need to follow the [Quick Repository Creation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Repository+Management) link under the upper right **"Welcome, admin"** link.

Choose the desired repository types and continue.